# How can I catch the key-double-click events in MFC?

Tags: mfc, keyevent

My application is trying to detect when a user double clicks the back quote (`) key on the keyboard. How do I do it?

Comment: Start a timer on the first backtick. If another backtick comes in while the timer is still running, you have a "double click". Kill the timer when it expires the first time, or when observing anything other than a backtick.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! So there's really no WM_ messages that help with this? Like this one for the mouse-double-click events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondblclk

Comment: There is no dedicated message that reports a certain key being pressed twice within a configurable timeout. That's just not generally useful. And keyboard input is much more involved than presses of a mouse button. Depending on your local settings, the backtick might be a [dead key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-deadchar).